# xsl fo - recognize where page breaks and draw a line

Tags: xsl-fo

Let's say I have a block with tables inside:

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:table page-break-inside="avoid">
    ...
    </fo:table>
    <fo:table page-break-inside="avoid">
    ...
    </fo:table>
...
</fo:block>
```

Is there a way to draw a line or put a border-bottom on the block whenever the block breaks?

See image below (The red line is what I need and missing).

[image]

I'm using Apache FOP.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish a border on a block to draw at the bottom of page breaks (and the top of the following page) then you would do this:

```
<fo:block border="1pt solid black" border-before-width.conditionality="retain" border-after-width.conditionality="retain">

<!-- lots of content here -->

</fo:block>
```

You "retain" the "before" and "after" width's of the border. If I just had content in the block, it would look like this:

[image]

However, your question is really unclear. You imply the "block" is breaking but you are talking about a border on the table as if the table itself is breaking. You can use those attributes on the table itself also to retain the border on the table but your sample shows no breaking inside the table so I have no idea if your table is breaking or not.

Comment: Can the style of the bottom border across page breaks be controlled at the cell level so that cells that span pages get a dashed grey line, for example? The table border style would apply when they don't span pages. See my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620898/make-cell-bottom-border-style-visible-but-different-from-tables-default-bottom