# Make cell bottom border style visible but different from table's default bottom border style if a row breaks across pages

Tags: xsl-fo

I've been researching various lists and sites, including stackoverflow, that lead me to believe that it might be possible to apply a unique bottom border when a row or cell breaks across a page boundary. The simple choices we've tried thus far is to use either border-after-width.conditionality set to either retain or discard. Each of these two options has visual drawbacks. It would ease readability if the viewer could quickly determine that a row or cell breaks across a page by having a border at the bottom the table fragment on the page that would be a grey color or a dashed line for example. Being able to control this at the cell object would be ideal since some cells would cross page boundaries where others wouldn't in the same row.

There are many table objects and FO border attributes and conditions that look like they might be able to be combined to produce the desired result, but I wouldn't know where to start. I first want to know if it's possible. If so, then how could this be implemented? I can then ask if Apache FOP honors those attributes.

Comment: Can you style your document such that the table in question is inside a page-sequence? If yes, you could likely accomplish what you want by discarding the border at page end and placing your colored/grey/dashed border in a footer region for the first, rest pages and not on the last page of the sequence.

Comment: As far as I know XSL-FO 1.1 does not have functionality to change table border styles when it breaks into pages. Instead our user uses extension that repeat the cell contents https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.repeat-cell-content-at-break or output "Continued" word using fo:retrieve-table-marker. The latter needs fo:table/fo:table-header nested in fo:table-cell and fo:table-header/fo:table-row/fo:table contains fo:retrieve-table-marker.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarity. I no longer need to spend time trying to magically make it work.